# Dropdown does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css

[JS beginner] I am working on a mobile menu that get trigger when you click one button.

The real problem is that the button don't get trigger in any way.

The other problem is that I want, when the menu open, the rest of the menu slides (moves) vertically down without interfering with the dropdown (submenu).

Here is my jsfiddle in case you want to test it: 
https://jsfiddle.net/u1cbsaje/#&togetherjs=c6zR1o4b45

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
nav {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #133966;
}
nav li {
    display:block;
}
nav li a,
.dropbtn {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 14px 0px 14px 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #F04D0C;
}
li.dropdown {
    display: block;
}
nav .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #133966;
    min-width: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    z-index: 10;
}
nav .dropdown-content a {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
nav .dropdown-content-side a {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
nav .dropdown-content-side {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #133966;
    min-width: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    z-index: 10;
}
nav .dropdown-content .dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #f1f1f1

}

nav .dropdown-content .dropdown-content-side a:hover {
    background-color: #f1f1f1
}
```

```html
<nav>
<ul>
  <li><a href="index.php" class="cmn-t-underline">Acasa</a></li>
  
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a  href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction() class="dropbtn"  style="cursor:pointer">Infinatri firme</a>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="infintare_societate_limitata.php"> Societate cu raspundere limitata (S.R.L.) </a>
        <a href="infintare_societate_limitata_d.php">Societate cu raspundere limitata - debutanti (S.R.L.-D)</a>
        <a href="infintare_societate_actiuni.php">Societate pe actiuni (S.A.)</a>
        <a href="infintare_persoana_fizica.php">Persoana fizica autorizata (P.F.A.)</a>
        <a href="infintare_interprindere_individuala.php">Intreprindere individuala (I.I.)</a>
        <a href="infintare_interprindere_familiala.php">Intreprindere familiala (I.F.)</a>
        <a href="infintare_cooperative.php">Cooperative</a>
        <a href="infintare_asociatii.php">Asociatii</a>
        <a href="infintare_fundatii.php">Fundatii</a>
        <a href="infintare_sindicate.php">Sindicate</a>
    </div>
  </li>

<li class="dropdown">
    <a  href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction() class="dropbtn"  style="cursor:pointer">Modificari</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
       <a href="modificari_actualizare_date.php">Actualizare date de identificare</a>
        <a href="modificari_deschiderepunct.php">Deschidere punct de lucru si autorizare activ</a>
        <a href="modificari_inchiderepunct.php">Inchidere punct de lucru</a>
        <a href="modificari_suspendare_reluare.php">Suspendare si reluare activitate</a>
        <a href="modificari_majorare_capital.php">Majorare capital social</a>
        <a href="modificari_reducere_capital.php">Reducere capital social</a>
        <a href="modificari_numire.php">Numire administrator</a>
        <a href="modificari_schimbare_revocare_admin.php">Revocare si schimbare administrator</a>
        <a href="modificari_modif.php">Modificare obiect de activitate</a>
        <a href="modificari_recod_extindere.php">Recodificare extindere obiect de activitate</a>
        <a href="modificari_radiere.php">Radiere obiect de activitate</a>
        <a href="modificari_schimbare_sediu.php">Schimbare sediu social</a>
        <a href="modificari_prelungire_sediu.php">Prelungire sediu social</a>
        <a href="modificari_autorizare_registru.php">Autorizare activitati registru comert</a>
        <a href="modificari_schimbare_denumire.php">Schimbare denumire firma</a>
        <a href="modificari_cesiune_firma.php">Cesiune firma</a>
    </div>
  </li>

<li class="dropdown">
     <a  href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction() class="dropbtn"  style="cursor:pointer">Inchidere</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content-side" id="myDropdown">
      <a href="inchidere_pfa.php">Inchidere (P.F.A)</a>
        <a href="inchidere_ii.php">Inchidere (I.I.)</a>
        <a href="inchidere_if.php">Inchidere (I.F.)</a>
        <a href="inchidere_srl.php">Inchidere (SRL - Radiere firma)</a>
    </div>
  </li>

<li class="dropdown">
    <a  href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction() class="dropbtn"  style="cursor:pointer">Gazdurie</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content-side" id="myDropdown">
        <a href="gazduire_sect1.php">Gazduire sediu social sector 1</a>
        <a href="gazduire_sect2.php">Gazduire sediu social sector 2</a>
        <a href="gazduire_sect3.php">Gazduire sediu social sector 3</a>
        <a href="gazduire_sect4.php">Gazduire sediu social sector 4</a>
        <a href="gazduire_sect5.php">Gazduire sediu social sector 5</a>
        <a href="gazduire_sect6.php">Gazduire sediu social sector 6</a>
    </div>
  </li>
<li><a href="modele.php" class="cmn-t-underline">Modele contracte</a></li>

    <li><a href="tarife.php" class="cmn-t-underline">Tarife</a></li>

    <li><a href="contact.php" class="cmn-t-underline">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Add a quote `onclick="myFunction() class="` should be `onclick="myFunction()" class="` also you have no class called show

Comment: That was my mistake but the syntax still dosen't work

Comment: There are many more issues. I suggest you start from a simple example and make that work first. The visible links do not show the clickable links for example